# What is wrong with this vim regular expression?

Tags: vim

I have a list of files with extension .elf like this

`file1.elf
 file2.elf
 file3.elf`

I am trying to run them in shell with run command like `run file1.elf >file1.log` and get the result in a log file with file name with .log addition.
My list of file is very big. I am trying out a vim regular expression so it will match the file name eg `file1` in `file1.elf` and use it to create name for the log file. I am trying out like this

`s/\(\(\<\w\+\)\@<=\.elf\)/\1 >\2\.log/`

Here i try to match a text which is proceeded by `.elf` and keep it in `\1` , i expect the entrire file name to be in it and `\2` i was hoping would just contain the file name minus extension. but this gives me 
`run file1 >file1.run` i.e `\1` dose not take the full file name, it has some how missed `.elf` extension. I can do `\1\.elf` to get proper result but i was wondering why the expression is not working as i expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `\@<=` in your match pattern. This is the *positiv lookahead* assertion. As per documentation (`:help /\@<=1`),

> Matches with zero width if the preceding atom matches just before what follows

The important part is that it *matches with zero width*, this is what you are experiancing, the `.elf` (which follows) is matched but with zero widht, so that `\1` does not contain the suffix `.elf`.

Instead, it would be easier to go with a

```
%s/\v(.*)\.elf$/run \1.elf > \1.log/
```

Here, I've used `\v` to turn on *very magic* (`:help magic`). With this turned on, you don't need al those backslashes when you use grouping parantheses.

Then there is `(.*)` to match and store the filename up until

`\.elf$` which seems to be each files suffix.

In the substitution part, after the `/` I add the literal `run` followed by `\1`. `\1` will be replaced by the stored filename (without `.elf` suffix).

Comment: Or assuming a space character before file1.elf then %s/\v(\s\S\+)(\.elf)$/run \1\2 > \1.log/

Answer (score 1):

The `\@<=` seems pointless and unneeded. Removing it gets you the desired behavior.

Comment: you are right, \@<= not required here. I realize now. I remember that i used this particular expression when my list had lot of other files with other extension which i then used to delete. I did not realize that the expression could be simplified. If i deleted unwanted files first and then use  a simpler expression